# Why does the 32769th insert fail in std::unordered_set?

Tags: c++, c++17, unordered-set

I generate a large number of class instances and store them in a `std::unordered_set`. I have defined a hash function and an equality relation, and so far everything works as it should - I insert 10000 instances with `unordered_set::insert`, and I can find them with `unordered_set::find`. All the objects are undamaged, and there is no hint on memory corruption or any other issue.

However, when I keep inserting, **the 32769th insert fails** - it doesn't throw, but it returns a pair where the iterator is `== nullptr` (0x00000000). `insert` is defined as:

```
pair<iterator, bool> insert(const value_type& Val);
```

and normally, the `*iterator` is the key I inserted, and the bool is `true`.
If I (after the error) try to find the object, it *is* in the set; if I try to insert it again, it tells me its already there; so the insert seems to have worked fine. Just the returned value is `pair<nullptr,true>` instead `pair<iterator,bool>`.
Note that if I hand-fill the iterator and continue in the debugger, the same issue happens again at the first insert after 65536, and then at 131072, etc. (so for 2^15+1, 2^16+1, 2^17+1, ...) - but not at 3 * 32768+1, etc.

To me, this looks like some `short` overflow. Maybe my hashes are really bad and lead to uneven filling of buckets, and at 32768 it runs out of buckets? I could not find anything more detailed about such a limit when googling, and I don't know enough about balanced trees or whatever this is internally.
Still, the std library code should be able to handle bad hashing, I understand if it gets slow and inefficient, but it shouldn't *fail*.

**Question: Why do the 2^15th+1, 2^16th+1, etc. inserts fail, and how can I avoid it?**

This is in Microsoft Visual Studio 2017  V15.7.1 (latest version as of 2018-05-15). Compiler is set to use C++2017 rules, but I doubt it makes any impact.
I cannot paste the complete code for a minimum viable solution, as the object generation is complex across multiple classes and methods, and has several hundreds lines of code, the generated hashes obviously depend on the details of the objects, and are not easily reproducible in dummy code.

**### Update after one day ###**: (I cannot put this in an answer, because the q was put on hold)
After extensive debugging of the standard library (including a lot of head-scratching), @JamesPoag's answer turns out to point to the right thing.
After `n` inserts, I get:

```
  n     load_factor  max_load_factor  bucket_count  max_bucket_count
32766   0.999938965  1.00000000       32768         536870911 (=2^29-1)
32767   0.999969482  1.00000000       32768         536870911
32768   1.000000000  1.00000000       32768         536870911
32769   0.500000000  1.00000000       65536         536870911
```

not surprising, after 32768 inserts, the load factor has reached its maximum. The 32769th insert triggers a rehash to bigger table, inside the internal method  _Check_Size:

```
void _Check_size()
        {    // grow table as needed
        if (max_load_factor() < load_factor())

            {    // rehash to bigger table
            size_type _Newsize = bucket_count();

            if (_Newsize < 512)
                _Newsize *= 8;    // multiply by 8
            else if (_Newsize < _Vec.max_size() / 2)
                _Newsize *= 2;    // multiply safely by 2
            _Init(_Newsize);
            _Reinsert();
            }
        }
```

at the end, `_Reinsert()` is called and fills all 32769 keys into the new buckets, and _sets all the `_next` and `_prev` pointers accordingly. That works fine.
However, the code that is calling those two looks like this (`Plist` is *my* set's name, this code gets generated from a template):

```
_Insert_bucket(_Plist, _Where, _Bucket);

_TRY_BEGIN
_Check_size();
_CATCH_ALL
erase(_Make_iter(_Plist));
_RERAISE;
_CATCH_END

return (_Pairib(_Make_iter(_Plist), true));
}
```

The critical point is in the last line - _Plist is used to build the pair, but it holds a now dead pointer to `_next`, because all bucket's addresses were rebuild in `_Check_size()`, some lines earlier.
I think this is an error in the std library - here it needs to find `_Plist` in the new set, where it looks the same, but has a valid `_next` pointer.

An easy 'fix' is (verified to work) to expand the set right before the critical `insert`:
`if (mySet.size() == mySet.bucket_count()) mySet.rehash(mySet.bucket_count() * 2);`.

**### Further Update: ###**
I have been trying extensively (16+ hours) to produce a *minimum code* that reproduces the issue, but I was not yet able to. I'll try to log the actual calculated hashes for the existing large code.
One thing I found is that one hash value of one of the keys *changed* (unintentionally) between being inserted and being rehashed. This *might* be the root cause; if I move the rehashing outside of the insert, the issue is gone.
I am not sure if there is a rule that hashes have to be constant, but it probably makes sense, how else could you find the key again.

Comment: You're not doing hacky `reinterpret_cast`s are you?

Comment: Nope. All clean.

Comment: Okay. Are your builds optimized *at all*? (Even inlining?) Furthermore, have you tried stepping through the diassembly to figure out exactly which instruction changes the value, then going back to see exactly where in the source code that is? If it's not your own code, it's probably either optimized away or it's in compiler-generated code, so the step you need to take is to figure out where this is happening.

Comment: @Aganju: "*I cannot paste the complete code for a minimum viable solution, as [...] and are not easily reproducible in dummy code.*" While I understand your dilemma, it's pretty much impossible for anyone (including Microsoft) to know why this is happening *without* all of those details either. After all, if you had to go debugging into the implementation to fix it, you'd need the specific code that caused the problem, right?

Comment: Why are you comparing iterators to `nullptr`?

Comment: Works on my machine.  The bug must be in the code not provided.

Comment: @user2357112 i am normally not, but it fails afterwards, so I traced it back to the library call and verified it returns nullptr as iterator.

Comment: @NicolBolas i hear you. I was hoping someone who understands how the std::unordered_set works, or had the issue before, knows about it. If you understand the structure, number of buckets limit might have a meaning for you that I don't have.

Comment: @Mehrdad , it definitely happens inside the std library call, and if you ever looked at that code, it is pretty hard to read. Tat will be my next approach though. Even if I find it, it might not help me - i can't change the standard library. I'd rather learn what I can do different to avoid it (balance the buckets? Or such a thing, does that make sense??)

Comment: Very funny, @Eljay . I thought I explained why I cannot provide the complete code. Even 32768 extracted and hardcoded hashes are a pretty long code.

Comment: @Aganju: Unfortunately you *will* have to get used to stepping through the standard library. I do that on a pretty regular basis now. [I used to not even be able to tell if it was human-generated](/q/7157308/541686) but now I've gotten used to reading it. If you get confused about a particular piece of their code just reply to me and I'll be happy to decipher it and explain it to you. But I'm afraid I don't really see another solution here.

Comment: @Aganju: Most likely it's not an issue with the standard library itself, but stepping through will help you figure out where (hypothetically) an implicit cast might be occurring that you don't expect, due to the way you're calling some function. That's happened to me before. (But heck, even if it is a bug in the standard library, that means you don't *want* to use a buggy implementation, so you *would* want to modify the standard library in that case! You'd just have to tell other people to patch their copy too. But in any case, you need to step through.)

Comment: Ok, on the coming weekend... :-/ i'll report back here when I find it. _If_ I find it

Comment: Is this a 32-bit program ?  What is `sizeof(value_type)` ?

Comment: @Aganju: Sure. Once you report back more info (so that we at least have a chance of seeing what's going on), let me know if you need a reopen vote; I think I might be able to reopen it with a single vote.

Comment: Does your application crash (as you'd expect) when you dereference that nullptr to get to the node?  Are you perhaps running on a 64-bit, and only looking at the lower 32-bits of the address?

Comment: The program was run and tested on 32 bit. I found the issue, see edit above.

Comment: What does "the iterator `== nullptr`" mean? You can't compare an iterator and a `nullptr_t`.

Comment: it means that the iterator gets returned from the std library with the value of 0x00000000 (seen in the debugger). That is of course an error, which is the root problem of this question. I found an error in the code in the std library code, which results in this illegal return value.

Comment: Now that you know the cause you should be able to create a MCVE ?

Comment: Of course hashes have to be constant: "[Container elements may not be modified (even by non const iterators) since modification could change an element's hash and corrupt the container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I plugged some simple code into godbolt.org to see what the output was, but nothing was jumping out at me.

I suspect that Value is inserted and the iterator is created, but the insertion exceeds the [max_load_factor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/max_load_factor/) and triggers a rehash.  On Rehash, the previous iterators are invalidated.  The return iterator might be zeroed out in this case (or never set) (again I can't find it in the disassembly).

Check the  load_value(), max_load_value() and bucket_count() before and after the offending insert.

Answer (score 1):

*[this is a self-answer]*
The issue is not in the standard library, as assumed, it is in my code after all (little surprise). Here is what happened:

I am inserting complex objects into the unordered_set, and the hash is calculated from the object. Let's say object 1 has the hash H1, object 2 has the hash H2, etc.
Further on, I am temporarily modifying the inserted object, cloning it, inserting the clone into the *unordered_set*, and undoing the modification. However, if the *insert* triggers a reorganization of the set (which happens at 2^15, 2^16, etc.), the hashes of all existing objects are recalculated.
As object 1 is currently 'temporarily modified', its hash is not coming back as H1, but different. That messes up the internal structure of the set, and it ends up returning an invalid iterator. Pseudocode:

```
myMap.insert(Object1);  // hash H1 is internally calculated
Object1.DoChange();     // temporary modification
Object2 = Clone(Object1);
myMap.insert(Object2);  // <-- problem - rehashes internally and finds different hash H1 for Object1 !
Object1.UndoChange();   // too late, damage done
```

The problem disappears if I move the rehashing outside the *insert*, or if I undo the modification of the object *before* the critical insert (so the hash is correct again).
There are several other ways to avoid the issue (clone *before* modifying, save the hash value at the object and don't recalculate, etc.).

**Core Lesson: Hash calculation *must* be stable. You cannot modify objects that are in a set or map, if it changes the calculated hash - the set or map might trigger a rehash at unexpected points of time.**

Comment: I'm sure in hindsight it seems obvious, but thanks for the warning and reminder.  I ran into somthing similar many years ago, where code would modify a string, do something with it, then modify it back.  Problem was, another thread was reading the string and saw the modifications that it shouldn't have.  Not fun to debug!